# Problem scanning strings with spaces in C

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have to scan a string with spaces so I can do somethings with it in this case moving the string n chars to the right or to the left. For example:

If I give n = 1, the string

```
house
```

becomes:

```
ehous
```

But the input can also be a string with spaces like, n being the same:

```
yellow house
```

becomes:

```
eyellow hous
```

So to scan the string im doing this:

```
char text[166];
scanf("%d %[^\n]%*c", &n, &text);
```

And everything works great, but now the I submitted the program I get this error:

```
src.c: In function 'main':
src.c:30:26: error: format '%[^
 ' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'char (*)[166]' [-Werror=format=]
 30 |             scanf("%d %[^\n]%*c", &nVezes, &texto);
    |                       ~~~^~                ~~~~~~
    |                          |                 |
    |                          char *            char (*)[166]
```

What can I solve this? Also I can't use these libraries string.h, strings.h, and stdlib.h.

Every bit of help is appreciated.

Comment: `texto` is already a pointer (by virtue of array/pointer conversion), remove the `'&'` from the beginning in the `scanf()` parameter list. E.g. (use `texto` not `&texto`)

Comment: It is recommended you read your input with `fgets()` and then pass the filled buffer to `sscanf()` for parsing, e.g. `char buf[256]; if (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) { if (sscanf (buf, "%d %165[^\n]%*c", &nVezes, texto) == 2) { /* you have valid conversions */ } }`. **Note:** you must include the *field-width* modifier any time you are reading strings to protect your array bounds. Otherwise, your use of `scanf()` is no safer than `gets()`. See [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102)

Comment: Perhaps mere pedantry, but string.h and stdlib.h are *not* libraries.  A header is not a library, and a library is not a header.  Understand the distinction before failing to recognize the distinction causes great confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` does not truly scan a *string* but `stdin`.
Instead OP want to read a *line* of user input into an `int` and *string*.

Save headaches - [ditch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ditch#Verb) `scanf()` with its many weaknesses.

```
//         v---------------------- missing width limit
//                        v------- do not use here
scanf("%d %[^\n]%*c", &n, &text);
//     ^ ^ ----------------------- possible to read more than 1 line
// return value not checked
```

---

Use `fgets()` [@David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67040446/problem-scanning-strings-with-spaces-in-c#comment118500833_67040526)

```
char text[166];
char line[sizeof text + 20];
if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
  if (sscanf(line, "%d %165[^\n]", &n, text) == 2) {
    Success();  // OP's code here
  }
}
```

Comment: When I try this, it gives me this error "implicit declaration of function ‘Success’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]gcc" 

Which #include is Success() from?

Comment: @TelmoAlexandre `Success();` is to be replaced with your code that is executed upon successful reading and scanning.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the char array as a pointer(*). when you pass an array in C as an argument to a function, the name of the array acts as a pointer to the start of the array.

So, you should pass the array as follows:

```
scanf("%d %[^\n]%*c", &n, text);
```

Comment: @JackLilhammers adding the `'s'` following `%[^\n]` is simply wrong. The `"%[..]"` conversion specifier is complete unto itself. Adding a trialing `'s'` would force `scanf()` to match a literal `'s'` in the input (which with `%[^\n]` would never match).

Comment: Further to @DavidC.Rankin adding a length constraint would be a good idea. Prevents overruns

Comment: Thank you so much, since this was the simplier answer I tried it first and the problem was gone and the program passed!